# $\int(x+1)\cdot f'(x)= x^3+x^2-x+c$ and $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$. What is $f(-1)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> $\int(x+1)\cdot f'(x)= x^3+x^2-x+c$ and $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$. What is $f(-1)$?

I took the derivative of both sides and then factored the quadratic equation on the right:

$$(x+1)\cdot f'(x)=3x^2+2x-1$$

$$(x+1)\cdot f'(x)=(3x-1)(x+1)$$

At this point, if I divide both sides of the equation by $x+1$, taking the integral becomes easy and I can figure out the answer as $3$.

Though, because we divided by $x+1$ at the beginning, we should note that $x\not = -1$. Therefore, I actually can't compute $f(-1)$.

Is there a different simple way of solving this problem?

Comment: $f(-1)$ still exists even if $f'(-1)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f'(x)=3x-1$ on $(-1,0]$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$\begin{align*}
f(0)-f(-1)&=\lim_{t\to -1,\ t>-1} f(0)-f(t)\\&=\lim_{t\to -1,\ t>-1} \int_t^0 (3x-1)\ dx\\&=-2.5
\end{align*}$$ hence we get $f(-1)=3$. In fact, if you have $f'(x)=3x-1$ for all $x\ne 1$, then mean value theorem implies the existence of $c_x\in (-1,x)\cup(x,-1)$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x-(-1)}=f'(c_x)$, hence
$$
\lim_{x\to -1} \frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x-(-1)}=\lim_{c\to -1}f'(c)=-4.
$$ So $f'(-1)=-4$ and there's no problem extending $f'(x)=3x-1$ to $x=-1$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why did you compute $f(0)-f(-1)$?

Comment: We have value of $f(0)$ and the target value if $f(-1)$, so I applied $$f(a)-f(b)=\int_b^a f'(x) dx$$ to $a=0$, $b\to -1$.